# Phone lock app for ios other than assistive touch

Tags: ios, applications, screen-lock

I would like to use an app to lock the screen instead of using the lock button. Right now I have set the tap on assistive touch to lock the screen but I don't like it always hovering above all other apps.

Is there any app that can lock the phone or make assistive touch appear only on the home screen?

Comment: If you are using iPhone X family, consider using a folio case which has the magnet.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to use triple-click on home button to activate Assistive Touch :

> Turn on AssistiveTouch
>
> When you turn on AssistiveTouch, you’ll see the AssistiveTouch menu. You can drag it to any edge of the screen, then tap the menu to open it.
>
> There are a few ways to turn on AssistiveTouch:
>       Go to Settings > General > Accessibility > AssistiveTouch, then turn on AssistiveTouch.
>       Tell Siri “Turn on AssistiveTouch.” 
>       Go to Settings > General > Accessibility > Accessibility Shortcut and turn on AssistiveTouch.
>
> When Accessibility Shortcut is on, you can turn AssistiveTouch on or off from any screen using Triple-click Home. Just press the Home button three times. To adjust the Triple-click speed, go to Settings > General > Accessibility > Home-click Speed.

https://support.apple.com/bg-bg/HT202658

This would turn a triple click on home button to a lock screen button click !

Another alternative which is not as good as the first one, I think, is to move all app icon which are in the bottom right of each of your screens so you could place assistive touch here and it won't be hovering an app icon as there is no more app icon here.

Finally, I don't think there is any app which could lock your screen without jailbreaking your iPhone.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doubly doesn’t work: a triple button press merely toggles the Assistive Touch button, and the Lock Screen action in it merely turns off the phone but does not lock the screen.